# Spring MVC using Google Cloud Platform MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to use GCP flexible environment for my Spring MVC demo app. I have created a MySQL database on GCP and my app is connected to it via pom.xml as described here [Using Cloud SQL for MySQL](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/using-cloud-sql). But I cant find info how to use Spring configuration XML file with this MySQL database. **Should I use both pom.xml and spring_config.xml data source bean to connect to it or just pom.xml?** BTW I am using ComboPooledDataSource:

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its good to maintain both. Generally pom is for maven dependencies and config file is for all configuration related tasks like db connectivity.

Comment: Thanks. I will use both as you suggest. Thought they may interfere with each other but good to know that it is not so.